# Conversion of IEnumerable<T> for Extension Method Issue

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have the following class and extension class (for this example):

```
public class Person<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public static class PersonExt
{
    public static void Process<TResult>(this Person<IEnumerable<TResult>> p)
    {
        // Do something with .Any().
        Console.WriteLine(p.Value.Any());
    }
}
```

I was expecting I could write something like the following and it would work, but it doesn't:

```
var x = new Person<List<String>>();
x.Process();
```

Since List is lower in the inheritance tree than IEnumerable, shouldn't this be valid? It works if I new up a `Person<IEnumerable<String>>` of course because that's the direct type.

I'm trying to use an extension method that can be applied to all `Person<T>`'s as long as T implements `IEnumerable<Something>` because I need to use the `.Any()` method.

EDIT: Maybe my understanding of covariance is off? I know `IEnumerable<String>` should convert to `IEnumerable<Object>`, but couldn't `IList<String>` convert to `IEnumerable<String>`?

EDIT2: Forgot to mention that I *am* using .net 4.0.

Comment: With respect to your edit, those are different concepts, `IList<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, that's why the conversion there is allowed, it's not necessary for it to be covariant or contravariant in that case.

Comment: Yeah I understand *now* about co/contravariance after doing some reading the past few minutes. So why isn't what I've written valid? It seems intuitive that it would be...

Comment: If you were doing this in C# 4.0 I would surmise that it'd work, but not with C# 3.0 and lower.

Comment: I was doing it in C#4.0 and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know `IEnumerable<String>` should
>   convert to `IEnumerable<Object>`, but
>   couldn't `IList<String>` convert to
>   `IEnumerable<String>`?

`IList<String>` can convert to `IEnumerable<String>`.  The problem is that you're trying to convert `Person<List<String>>` to `Person<IEnumerable<String>>`, which is illegal.  For example, it's perfectly valid to write:

```
var x = new Person<IEnumerable<String>>();
x.Value = new string[0];
```

since Value is of type `IEnumerable<String>` and a string array is an `IEnumerable<String>`.  However, you cannot write:

```
var x = new Person<List<String>>();
x.Value = new string[0];
```

since Value is of type `List<String>`.  Since you can't use a `Person<List<String>>` in all places where you could use a `Person<IEnumerable<String>>`, it's not a legal cast.

Note that you can do something similar to what you want if you add a second type parameter to your extension method:

```
public static void Process<TResult, TList>(this Person<TList> p)
    where TList : IEnumerable<TResult>
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Value.Any());
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler won't be able to infer both type parameters, so you would have to call it like this:

```
var x = new Person<List<String>>();
x.Process<String, List<String>>();
```

If you are using C# 4.0 and can use covariance, then you can define a covariant *interface* for person:

```
public interface IPerson<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Person<T>
    : IPerson<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then write your extension method as:

```
public static void Process<TResult>(this IPerson<IEnumerable<TResult>> p)
{
    // Do something with .Any().
    Console.WriteLine(p.Value.Any());
}
```

Since `IPerson<T>.Value` is read-only, a `IPerson<List<String>>` can be used everywhere that an `IPerson<IEnumerable<String>>` can be, and the conversion is valid.

Comment: Yeah I was just missing the `out` keyword on the interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you've quite grasped the correct use of generics. In any event ...

The only thing that is incorrect is your declaration of extension method, and the way you are attempting to constrain the extension method.

```
public static class ThingExtensions
{
    public static void Process<T>(this Thing<T> p)
        where T : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        // Do something with .Any().
        Console.WriteLine(p.Value.Any());
    }
}
```

All I've really done is rename `Person` to `Thing` so that we're not getting hung up on what a `Person<List<string>>` really is.

```
public class Thing<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

class ListOfString : List<string>
{ }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Thing<ListOfString>();
        x.Value = new ListOfString();
        x.Process();

        x.Value.Add("asd");
        x.Process();


        var x2 = new Thing<int>();
        // Error    1   The type 'int' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' 
        // in the generic type or method 
        // 'ThingExtensions.Process<T>(Thing<T>)'. 
        // There is no boxing conversion from 'int' to 
        // 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'.    
        //x2.Process();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

You could also move the generic constraint to the `Thing<T>` if that was more applicable.

Comment: I should have mentioned this is a Console app with .net 3.5 (VS 2008)

Comment: You can also just substitute `ListOfString` with `List<string>` or anything that implements `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 0):

You mention covariance, but don't actually use it. You have to specify `in` or `out` on your generic parameters. Note that co/contravariance doesn't work on class types; they must be applied to interfaces.

So, introducing an interface and making it covariant:

```
public interface IPerson<out T>
{
  T Value { get; }
}

public class Person<T> : IPerson<T>
{
  public T Value { get; set; }
}

public static class PersonExt
{
  public static void Process<TResult>(this IPerson<IEnumerable<TResult>> p)
  {
    // Do something with .Any(). 
    Console.WriteLine(p.Value.Any());
  }
}
```

allows this code to compile:

```
var x = new Person<List<String>>();  
x.Process();
```